# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contact_data has no column named timestamp_

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jdbc

Well, what I'm trying to do is to uodate my app in the first install. So in the first access my app has a service that access the CallLog, and retrieve all data and insert in the app DB.

And I have a column `timestamp_` that I want to insert the timestamp of the call. But when I try to insert it says the table has no column named timestamp_, and it is explicity written in the sql string this name of the column. I dont know why is it doing that.

My CREATE TABLE String is written in the `strings.xml`, and I access this string and split it getting each line.

Here is the code of the Service, the SQL String, and after there is the code of the DataHandlerDB, that has the method that creates the DB.

**My Service:**

```
package com.myapp.test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.rogercg.phonestatistics.CallDataHelper.OpenHelper;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RatedCallsService extends Service {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "RatedCallsService";
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private OpenHelper helper;
    private String theDate;
    private String theMonth_;
    private String theYear_;
    private String theDay_;
    public static boolean servReg = false;

    class RatedCallsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public RatedCallsContentObserver(Handler h) {

            super(h);
            helper = new OpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
            db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "constructor");

        }

        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "deliver self");
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "selfchange " + selfChange);
            searchInsert();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        servReg = true;
        helper = new OpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
        db = DataHandlerDB.createDB(this);

        registerContentObserver();

        Cursor dbsize = DataHandlerDB.selectTopCalls(this
                .getApplicationContext());
        if (dbsize.getCount() == 0) {

            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Updating Database.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Atualizou " + dbsize.getCount());
            updateDB();

        }
        Cursor currsize = DataHandlerDB.selectTopCalls(this
                .getApplicationContext());
        currsize.moveToFirst();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "cursize " + currsize.getCount());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
        this.getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .unregisterContentObserver(
                        new RatedCallsContentObserver(handler));
        servReg = false;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;

    }

    protected void searchInsert() {

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            int numberColumnId = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
            int durationId = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
            int contactNameId = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
            int numTypeId = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE);
            int callTypeId = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
            int dateColumnId = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);

            Date dt = new Date();
            int hours = dt.getHours();
            int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
            int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
            String currTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");

            Date date = new Date();

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnId);
            String contactName = (null == cursor.getString(contactNameId) ? ""
                    : cursor.getString(contactNameId));
            String duration = cursor.getString(durationId);
            String numType = cursor.getString(numTypeId);
            String callType = cursor.getString(callTypeId);
            String dateColumn = cursor.getString(dateColumnId);

            seconds = Integer.parseInt(duration);

            theDate = dateFormat.format(date);

            if (theDate.length() == 9) {

                theMonth_ = theDate.substring(0, 1);
                theDay_ = theDate.substring(2, 4);
                theYear_ = theDate.substring(5, 9);

            } else if (theDate.length() == 10) {

                theMonth_ = theDate.substring(0, 2);
                theDay_ = theDate.substring(3, 4);
                theYear_ = theDate.substring(6, 10);

            } else if (theDate.length() == 8) {

                theMonth_ = theDate.substring(0, 1);
                theDay_ = theDate.substring(2, 3);
                theYear_ = theDate.substring(4, 8);

            }

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();

            values.put("contact_id", 1);
            values.put("contact_name", contactName);
            values.put("number_type", numType);
            values.put("contact_number", contactNumber);
            values.put("duration", Utilities.convertTime(seconds));
            values.put("date", dateFormat.format(date));
            values.put("timestamp_", dateColumn);
            values.put("current_time", currTime);
            values.put("cont", 1);
            values.put("type", callType);

            values2.put("month",
                    Utilities.monthName(Integer.parseInt(theMonth_)));
            values2.put("duration", Utilities.convertTime(seconds));
            values2.put("year", theYear_);
            values2.put("month_num", Integer.parseInt(theMonth_));

            if (!db.isOpen()) {
                db = getApplicationContext()
                        .openOrCreateDatabase(
                                "/data/data/com.myapp.test/databases/calls.db",
                                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
            }
            if (duration != "") {
                if (Integer.parseInt(duration) != 0) {

                    String existingMonthDuration = DataHandlerDB
                            .selectMonthsDuration(theMonth_, theYear_, this);
                    Integer newMonthDuration;

                    // Verifica se ja existe mes no MONTHS_DUR
                    if (existingMonthDuration != "") {

                        newMonthDuration = Integer
                                .parseInt(existingMonthDuration)
                                + Integer.parseInt(duration);

                        values2.put("duration",
                                Utilities.convertTime(newMonthDuration));

                        db.update(DataHandlerDB.MONTHS_DUR, values2,
                                "year = ?", new String[] { theYear_ });

                    } else {

                        db.insert(DataHandlerDB.MONTHS_DUR, null, values2);

                    }

                    Cursor c = DataHandlerDB.selectTimeStamp(this
                            .getApplicationContext());
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "c.getstr8: " + c.getString(8));
                        if (!c.getString(8).equals(dateColumn)) {
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Antes do db.insert line 202");
                            db.insert(DataHandlerDB.CONTACT_DATA, null, values);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    protected void updateDB() {

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                null);
        
        cursor.moveToFirst();

            do {

                int numberColumnId = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
                int durationId = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
                int contactNameId = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
                int numTypeId = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE);
                int callTypeId = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
                int dateColumnId = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);

                Date dt = new Date();
                int hours = dt.getHours();
                int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                String currTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");

                Date date = new Date();

                String contactNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnId);
                String contactName = (null == cursor.getString(contactNameId) ? ""
                        : cursor.getString(contactNameId));
                String duration = cursor.getString(durationId);
                String numType = cursor.getString(numTypeId);
                String callType = cursor.getString(callTypeId);
                String dateColumn = cursor.getString(dateColumnId);

                seconds = Integer.parseInt(duration);

                theDate = dateFormat.format(date);

                if (theDate.length() == 9) {

                    theMonth_ = theDate.substring(0, 1);
                    theDay_ = theDate.substring(2, 4);
                    theYear_ = theDate.substring(5, 9);

                } else if (theDate.length() == 10) {

                    theMonth_ = theDate.substring(0, 2);
                    theDay_ = theDate.substring(3, 4);
                    theYear_ = theDate.substring(6, 10);

                } else if (theDate.length() == 8) {

                    theMonth_ = theDate.substring(0, 1);
                    theDay_ = theDate.substring(2, 3);
                    theYear_ = theDate.substring(4, 8);

                }

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();

                values.put("contact_id", 1);
                values.put("contact_name", contactName);
                values.put("number_type", numType);
                values.put("contact_number", contactNumber);
                values.put("duration", Utilities.convertTime(seconds));
                values.put("date", dateFormat.format(date));
                values.put("timestamp_", dateColumn);
                values.put("current_time", currTime);
                values.put("cont", 1);
                values.put("type", callType);

                values2.put("month",
                        Utilities.monthName(Integer.parseInt(theMonth_)));
                values2.put("duration", Utilities.convertTime(seconds));
                values2.put("year", theYear_);
                values2.put("month_num", Integer.parseInt(theMonth_));

                if (!db.isOpen()) {
                    db = getApplicationContext()
                            .openOrCreateDatabase(
                                    "/data/data/com.myapp.test/databases/calls.db",
                                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
                }
                if (duration != "") {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(duration) != 0) {

                        String existingMonthDuration = DataHandlerDB
                                .selectMonthsDuration(theMonth_, theYear_, this);
                        Integer newMonthDuration;

                        // Verifica se ja existe mes no MONTHS_DUR
                        if (existingMonthDuration != "") {

                            newMonthDuration = Integer
                                    .parseInt(existingMonthDuration)
                                    + Integer.parseInt(duration);

                            values2.put("duration",
                                    Utilities.convertTime(newMonthDuration));

                            db.update(DataHandlerDB.MONTHS_DUR, values2,
                                    "year = ?", new String[] { theYear_ });

                        } else {

                            db.insert(DataHandlerDB.MONTHS_DUR, null, values2);

                        }
                        db.insert(DataHandlerDB.CONTACT_DATA, null, values);
                    }
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());      
        cursor.close();
    }

    public void registerContentObserver() {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Registrou ContentObserver");
        this.getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(
                        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true,
                        new RatedCallsContentObserver(handler));
    }
}
```

---

**My DataHandlerDB.(Deals with database):**

```
public class DataHandlerDB {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "calls.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
protected static final String RATED_CONTACTS = "rated_contacts";
protected static final String CONTACT_DATA = "contact_data";
protected static final String MONTHS_DUR = "months_dur";
private static final String LOG_TAG = "DataHandlerDB";

protected static String CONTACT__ID_COL = "_id";
protected static String CONTACT_NAME_COL = "contact_name";
protected static String CONTACT_NUMBER_COL = "contact_number";
protected static String CONTACT_DURATION_COL = "duration";
protected static String CONTACT_DATE_COL = "date";
protected static String CONTACT_MONTH_COL = "month";

// create the DB
public static SQLiteDatabase createDB(Context ctx) {
    OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(ctx);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    helper.onCreate(db);
    helper.onOpen(db);
    db.close();
    return db;
}

public static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context mContext;

    OpenHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    
        String[] sql = mContext.getString(
                R.string.My_OnCreate).split("\n");          
        db.beginTransaction();

        try {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "entrou no try");
            execMultipleSQL(db, sql);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();                              
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            Log.e("Error creating tables and debug data ", e.toString());
            throw e;

        } finally {
            
            db.endTransaction();

        }
    }

    private void execMultipleSQL(SQLiteDatabase db, String[] sql) {

        for (String s : sql) {

            if (s.trim().length() > 0) {

                db.execSQL(s);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Str sql " + s);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        /*
         * Log.w("RatedContacts Database",
         * "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
         * db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + RATED_CONTACTS); onCreate(db);
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        super.onOpen(db);
    }

}

}
```

**The SQL String (declared in strings.xml):**

```
<string name="My_OnCreate">
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contact_data ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, contact_id INTEGER, contact_name VARCHAR(50), number_type VARCHAR(50), contact_number VARCHAR(50), duration TIME, duration_sum TIME, date DATE, timestamp_ VARCHAR(50), current_time TIME, cont INTEGER, type VARCHAR(50), month VARCHAR(50), day VARCHAR(50), year VARCHAR(50) );
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rated_contacts ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, contact_id INTEGER, contact_name VARCHAR(50), number_type VARCHAR(50), contact_number VARCHAR(50), duration TIME, duration_sum TIME, date DATE, timestamp_ VARCHAR(50), current_time TIME, cont INTEGER, type VARCHAR(50), month VARCHAR(50), day VARCHAR(50), year VARCHAR(50) );
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS months_dur ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, month VARCHAR(50), duration TIME, year VARCHAR(250), month_num INTEGER );"
    </string>
```

**Here is the error from the LogCat:**

> 06-13 18:58:05.041:
> INFO/Database(2121): sqlite returned:
> error code = 1, msg = table
> contact_data has no column named
> timestamp_
>
> 06-13 18:58:05.081:
> ERROR/Database(2121): Error inserting
> contact_number=1234545
> duration=00:00:05 contact_id=1
> timestamp_=1307928304514 number_type=0
> contact_name= current_time=18:58:4
> type=2 cont=1 date=6/13/2011 06-13
> 18:58:05.081:
>
> ERROR/Database(2121):
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
> table contact_data has no column named
> timestamp_: , while compiling: INSERT
> INTO contact_data(contact_number,
> duration, contact_id, timestamp_,
> number_type, contact_name,
> current_time, type, cont, date)
> VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is an error in the binding code between Java and SQLite. Can you try renaming "timestamp_" to "time_stamp", for a test?

Comment: The error persists with time_stamp.

PS: I was naming it only timestamp, and I though it was the cause, and I named it timestamp_ and the error persists. But this is not the problem because the second sql statement (that declares the table rated_contacts) create this column, but not for the first table.